# Antipole Clustering

Tags: database, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I made a photo mosaic script (PHP). This script has one picture and changes it to a photo buildup of little pictures. From a distance it looks like the real picture, when you move closer you see it are all little pictures. I take a square of a fixed number of pixels and determine the average color of that square. Then I compare this with my database which contains the average color of a couple thousand of pictures. I determine the color distance with all available images. But to run this script fully it takes a couple of minutes.

The bottleneck is matching the best picture with a part of the main picture. I have been searching online how to reduce this and came a cross “Antipole Clustering.” Of course I tried to find some information on how to use this method myself but I can’t seem to figure out what to do.

There are two steps. 1. Database acquisition and 2. Photomosaic creation.
Let’s start with step one, when this is all clear. Maybe I understand step 2 myself.

Step 1:

- partition each image of the database into 9 equal rectangles arranged in a 3x3 grid
- compute the RGB mean values for each rectangle
- construct a vector x composed by 27 components (three RGB components for each rectangle)
- x is the feature vector of the image in the data structure

Well, point 1 and 2 are easy but what should I do at point 3. How do I compose a vector X out of the 27 components (9 * R mean, G mean, B mean.)

And when I succeed to compose the vector, what is the next step I should do with this vector.

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I think the feature vector is computed:

You have 3 x 3 = 9 rectangles.

Each pixel is essentially 3 numbers, 1 for each of the Red, Green, and Blue color channels.

For each rectangle you compute the mean for the red, green, and blue colors for all the pixels in that rectangle. This gives you 3 numbers for each rectangle.

In total, you have 9 (rectangles) x 3 (mean for R, G, B) = 27 numbers.

Simply concatenate these 27 numbers into a single 27 by 1 (often written as 27 x 1) vector. That is 27 numbers grouped together. This vector of 27 numbers is the feature vector X that represents the color statistic of your photo. In the code, if you are using C++, this will probably be an array of 27 number or perhaps even an instance of the (aptly named) vector class. You can think of this feature vector as some form of "summary" of what the color in the photo is like. Roughly, things look like this: [R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2, ..., R9, G9, B9] where R1 is the mean/average of red pixels in the first rectangle and so on.

I believe step 2 involves some form of comparing these feature vectors so that those with similar feature vectors (and hence similar color) will be placed together. Comparison will likely involve the use of the Euclidean distance (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)), or some other metric, to compare how similar the feature vectors (and hence the photos' color) are to each other.

Lastly, as Anony-Mousse suggested, converting your pixels from RGB to HSB/HSV color would be preferable. If you use OpenCV or have access to it, this is simply a one liner code. Otherwise wiki HSV etc. will give your the math formula to perform the conversion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: IMO the article about vector compression and how to represent the color is v(x) = current pixel - right pixel and v(y) = current pixel - bottom pixel. Together it makes a v(x,y). It dont really understand why a n x 1...27 array of concatenated numbers is called a feature vector? A vector is something with a direction in euklidian mathematics and when you concatenate it it's not a vector?

Comment: The word "feature" is just a term that is often taken to mean some "statistic" that you calculate to describe/summarize an object (e.g. mean, variance, or whatever you can think up). This is a term common in computer vision and machine learning. Essentially, by representing the image as a feature vector, you are representing it as a point in n dimensional space (not direction). Granted "vector" may not be the right word in the mathematical sense when it is meant as a point but this is the term that is used by the research community...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using RGB, you might want to use HSB space. It gives better results for a wide variety of use cases. Put more weight on Hue to get better color matches for photos, or to brightness when composing high-contrast images (logos etc.)

I have never heard of antipole clustering. But the obvious next step would be to put all the images you have into a large index. Say, an R-Tree. Maybe bulk-load it via STR. Then you can quickly find matches.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it means vector quantization (vq). In vq the image isn't subdivide in rectangles but in density areas. Then you can take a mean point of this cluster. First off you need to take all colors and pixels separate and transfer it to a vector with XY coordinate. Then you can use a density clustering like voronoi cells and get the mean point. This point can you compare with other pictures in the database. Read here about VQ: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3090/image_compression_with_vector_.php.

How to plot vector from adjacent pixel:

```
d(x) = I(x+1,y) - I(x,y)
d(y) = I(x,y+1) - I(x,y)
```

Here's another link: http://www.leptonica.com/color-quantization.html.

Update: When you have already computed the mean color of your thumbnail you can proceed and sort all the means color in a rgb map and using the formula I give to you to compute the vector x. Now that you have a vector of all your thumbnails you can use the antipole tree to search for a thumbnail. This is possbile because the antipole tree is something like a kd-tree and subdivide the 2d space. Read here about antipole tree: http://matt.eifelle.com/2012/01/17/qtmosaic-0-2-faster-mosaics/. Maybe you can ask the author and download the sourcecode?

Comment: I have read some articles and seen some guide about VQ now. If I’m correct it works by dividing a large set of density points into groups having approximately the same number of points closest to them. Every group gets a mean point. 
What I couldn’t figure out was how to go from a 3D RGB to vector with XY coordinate.

Comment: Update my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand your answer. Let’s say I have a picture. With the first pixel 255,255,255 (white) and a second pixel 0,0,0 (black). How do I get from this to a density? From which I can start with VQ.  
Maybe you know an article or another guide which explains this.

Comment: Then your v(x) = r255,g255,b255. You didn't say what third pixel do you have for v(y). There isn't any other guide. You need to pay.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t seems to figure out how to get the vector.  Maybe it’s because I am not sure what a vector is. When I got the mean color of all thumbnails in my database I could make a vector. For example 10 thumbnails:  1) 0.255.0 2) 0.128.255 3) 255.128.0 4) 128.64.64 5) 128.128.0 6) 192.192.192 7) 128.255.128 8) 64.0.0 9) 0.255.255 10) 0.0.128. This are the colors how can I make a vector.

Comment: I'm not sure either. There is nothing about it in the papers. Personally I don't think you need a vector or antipole cluster. A trie is also very fast. In my formula you need 2 pixel to compute a vector. This pixel is in the image. But it makes no sense to me to compute a vector from a mean color. To you?