# Algorithms for finding a look alike face?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

I'm doing a personal project of trying to find a person's look-alike given a database of photographs of other people all taken in a consistent manner - people looking directly into the camera, neutral expression and no tilt to the head (think passport photo).

I have a system for placing markers for 2d coordinates on the faces and I was wondering if there are any known approaches for finding a look alike of that face given this approach?

I found the following facial recognition algorithms:
http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/

But none deal with the specific task of finding a look-alike.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I doubt you will find any algorithms that do what you want. You will need to figure out how to determine when face "look alike" and build an algorithm to do that. If you're lucky the grid of 2D coordinates that you create to describe a face will be the core of that algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can also try searching for "Face Verification" rather than just "Face Recognition". This might give you more relevant results.

Strictly speaking, the 2 are actually different things in scientific literature but are  sometimes lumped under face recognition. For details on their differences and some sample code, take a look here: http://www.idiap.ch/~marcel/labs/faceverif.php

However, for your purposes, what others such as Edvard and Ari has kindly suggested would work too. Basically they are suggesting a K-nearest neighbor style face recognition classifier. 
As a start, you can probably try that. First, compute a feature vector for each of your face images in your database. One possible feature to use is the Local Binary Pattern (LBP). You can find the code by googling it. Do the same for your query image. Now, loop through all the feature vectors and compare them to that of your query image using euclidean distance and return the K nearest ones.

While the above method is easy to code, it will generally not be as robust as some of the more sophisticated ones because they generally fail badly when faces are not aligned (known as unconstrained pose. Search for "Labelled Faces in the Wild" to see the results for state of the art for this problem.) or taken under different environmental conditions. But if the faces in your database are aligned and taken under similar conditions as you mentioned, then it might just work. If they are not aligned, you can use the face key points, which you mentioned you are able to compute, to align the faces. In general, comparing faces which are not aligned is a very difficult problem in computer vision and is still a very active area of research. But, if you only consider faces that look alike and in the same pose to be similar (i.e. similar in pose as well as looks) then this shouldn't be a problem.

The website your gave have links to the code for Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces. These are essentially 2 methods for computing feature vectors for your face images. Faces are identified by doing a K nearest neighbor search for faces in the database with feature vectors (computed using PCA and LDA respectively) closest to that of the query image.

I should probably also mention that in the Fisherfaces method, you will need to have "labels" for the faces in your database to identify the faces. This is because Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA), the classification method used in Fisherfaces, needs this information to compute a projection matrix that will project feature vectors for similar faces close together and dissimilar ones far apart. Comparison is then performed on these projected vectors. Here lies the difference between Face Recognition and Face Verification: for recognition, you need to have "labels" your training images in your database i.e. you need to identify them. 
For verification, you are only trying to tell whether any 2 given faces are of the same person. Often, you don't need the "labelled" data in the traditional sense (although some methods might make use of auxiliary training data to help in the face verification).

The code for computing Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces are available in OpenCV in case you use it.

As a side note:
A feature vector is actually just a vector in your linear algebra sense. It is simply n numbers packed together. The word "feature" refers to something like a "statistic" i.e. a feature vector is a vector containing statistics that characterizes the object it represents. For e.g., for the task of face recognition, the simplest feature vector would be the intensity values of the grayscale image of the face. In that case, I just reshape the 2D array of numbers into a n rows by 1 column vector, each entry containing the value of one pixel. The pixel value here is the "feature", and the n x 1 vector of pixel values is the feature vector. In the LBP case, roughly speaking, it computes a histogram at small patches of pixels in the image and joins these histograms together into one histogram, which is then used as the feature vector. So the Local Binary Pattern is the statistic and the histograms joined together is the feature vector. Together they described the "texture" and facial patterns of your face.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more a bout feature vector? I'm reading about vector compression and there too you need to pick a feature vector of the color.

Comment: @phpdevpad I added a paragraph to clarify the part on feature vectors. I think for you case, the feature vector could be just the 3 x 1 vector containing the RGB values, 1 for each pixel in the image. In vector compression/quantization, you cluster these feature vectors to form a codebook/dictionary of K clusters (usually using K Means), then replace each pixel with the cluster center of the cluster it is closest to. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry it was about antipole clustering. I gave this answer to somebody: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288571/antipole-clustering because in antipole clustering you pick a feature vector of 27 rgb values. Does this mean you just sum them up? In your word n x 27?? In vector compression I wrote a vector f(x,y) is the current pixel value c(x,y) - the adjacent pixel r(x1,y1) to the right and the adjacent pixel at the bottom b(x2,y2)?

Comment: @Phpdevpad I answered your question in your separate post. Hope it helps :).

Comment: Thanks so much for the great explanation! I will def give your suggestion a try. As a follow up question, do you know how I could expand your approach to be able to explain "why" the faces are similar. For example: the top two results match because the noses are 80% similar, eyes 20%, mouth 40% etc..? Is it just a matter of grouping the features and doing k-nearest search on those sub groups of a face?

Comment: @user257543 Off the top of my head, I suppose after you have found the closest match(es), you can compute similarity between each patch (eye, nose etc.) as you suggested and try to display that value as a percentage. For that, perhaps using the cosine similarity would be more appropriate and you can take it that 0 degree difference between the "normalized" vectors to be 100% match and 90 degree difference to be 0% match although I should stress that this is more of a quick "hack" i.e. it need not correspond to a true probability in a math sense.

Comment: Great, thank you, I'll give it a shot. Any thoughts on using earth mover's distance between two sets of 2d markers?

Comment: @user257543 Are you trying to get a measure of similarity between the shape described by 2 sets of 2D markers placed on the face? While I'm not familiar with EMD per se, if comparing the markers is what you want then try googling for "A Brief Introduction to Statistical Shape Analysis" by MB Steigman. It introduces ways to compare sets of points before going on to introduce Active Shape Model (ASM), the "precursor" to AAM, both of which you can consider since it seems that your 2D markers may provide additional info. Steigman also has other articles you can search for. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These two would seem like the equivalent problem, but I do not work in the field. You essentially have the following two problems:

1. Face recognition: Take a face and try to match it to a person.
2. Find similar faces: Take a face and try to find similar faces.

Aren't these equivalent? In (1) you start with a picture that you want to match to the owner and you compare it to a database of reference pictures for each person you know. In (2) you pick a picture in your reference database and run (1) for that picture against the other pictures in the database.

Since the algorithms seem to give you a measure of how likely two pictures belong to the same person, in (2) you just sort the measures in decreasing order and pick the top hits.

Comment: I think the problem is different, in the recognition task, you're trying to identify which other photos match the current photo, while finding similar faces is more like having a set of photos and trying to categorize them based on similarities. There should be a faster way to do the latter instead of doing `n^2` recognitions.

Comment: Well, some of the algorithms on the website seem to compute some metric which can be used for classification while others work by comparing two images. The former can be used to precompute metrics for a faster classification.

Comment: On another note, the OP hasn't specified what number of pictures the database contains.

Comment: @LieRyan Even when performing nearest neighbor comparison, there are methods to do some preprocessing on the database to speed up K nearest neighbor computation without hitting O(n^2) for e.g. AESA etc. I believe this is what Edvard is referring to. Further, there are approximate nearest neighbor which can be leverage for faster search although dimensionality of the feature vectors will come into play...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should first analyze all the picture in your database with whatever approach you are using. You should then have a set of metrics for each picture which you can compare a specific picture with and statistically find the closest match.

For example, if you can measure the distance between the eyes, you can find faces that have the same distance. You can then find the face that has the overall closest match and return that.